# Separate columns after the nth occurrence of a character

Tags: r, tidyr

I am a bit puzzled by separating columns using the separate function in tidyr:

My data frame looks like this

```r
library(tidyverse)

df=tibble(col1 = c("2397_A_run379_CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001", 
                   "3779_A_run535_TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001", 
                   "4958_BV_run685_GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001"))

df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 1
#>   col1                                   
#>   <chr>                                  
#> 1 2397_A_run379_CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
#> 2 3779_A_run535_TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001 
#> 3 4958_BV_run685_GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I want to create three dataframes where I separate everything based on the first "_",
then based on the second "_" and then by the third "_".

I want something like this:

```
> df1 
 
col1   col2
2397  A_run379_CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
3779  A_run535_TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001 
4958  BV_run685_GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001
```

```
> df2 
 
col1      col2
2397_A   run379_CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
3779_A   run535_TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001 
4958_BV  run685_GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001
```

```
> df3 
 
col1           col2
2397_A_run379  CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
3779_A_run535  TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001 
4958_BV_run685 GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001
```

Any help or guidance are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is some regex magic but a "brute-force" approach using `tidyr::extract` may look like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  extract(col1, into = c("col1", "col2"), "^(.*?)_(.*)$")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   col1  col2                              
#>   <chr> <chr>                             
#> 1 2397  A_run379_CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
#> 2 3779  A_run535_TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001 
#> 3 4958  BV_run685_GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001

df |>
  extract(col1, into = c("col1", "col2"), "^(.*?_.*?)_(.*)$")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   col1    col2                            
#>   <chr>   <chr>                           
#> 1 2397_A  run379_CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
#> 2 3779_A  run535_TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001 
#> 3 4958_BV run685_GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001

df |>
  extract(col1, into = c("col1", "col2"), "^(.*?_.*?_.*?)_(.*)$")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   col1           col2                     
#>   <chr>          <chr>                    
#> 1 2397_A_run379  CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
#> 2 3779_A_run535  TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001 
#> 3 4958_BV_run685 GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001
```

Answer (score 6):

Split all by `"_"`, and paste it back as desired:

```
s <- strsplit(df$col1, "_")

lapply(1:3, function(i)
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(s, function(j){
            data.frame(
              col1 = paste(j[ 1:i ], collapse = "_"),
              col2 = paste(j[ (i + 1):length(j) ], collapse = "_")
            )
          })))
# [[1]]
#   col1                               col2
# 1 2397 A_run379_CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
# 2 3779  A_run535_TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001
# 3 4958 BV_run685_GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001
# 
# [[2]]
#      col1                             col2
# 1  2397_A run379_CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
# 2  3779_A  run535_TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001
# 3 4958_BV  run685_GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001
# 
# [[3]]
#             col1                      col2
# 1  2397_A_run379 CTTGTACT_S119_L004_R1_001
# 2  3779_A_run535  TTATAGCC_S91_L003_R1_001
# 3 4958_BV_run685  GCGTACGT_S89_L005_R1_001
```